# Finding the number of relations on set S

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know the number of reflexive relations on a finite set is: $2^{n^{2}-n}$

The number of symmetric relations is: $2^{n+1 \choose 2} $

The number of antisymmetric relations: $2^{n}3^{n \choose 2}$

But, how do I find the number of relations that are:

non-symmetric relations on S.

number of symmetric relations which are also antisymmetric on S.

number of non-symmetric relations which are also antisymmetric on S.

Comment: Early apologies about the terrible spacing and newlines...

Comment: What is meant by non-symmetric? Asymmetric or not symmetric? I expect the first mentioned. If not then it is (off course) the total number of relations minus the number of symmetric relations.